# tables from product customization options. a table for each option or one table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to design a database for a food ordering system.

example pizza.

one pizza can have 0 toppings or 10.

im writing this using a php framework with an orm that creates relationships.

is it better to

1. create 1 table for the item (Pizza)

and then create a table for each topping and then relate them.

or

2. create 1 table for the pizza and create another table that contains all of the toppings as columns and every pizza that is ordered a new row created with each column set to true or false to be added to the pizza with a foreign key to relate the toppings and pizza?

thanks

Comment: Can a pizza really have 0 toppings? Isn't that 'bread'? Anyway, both ideas are terrible- see normalisation

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is 
1) create one table for pizza like:

```
id   1
name Capriciossa
```

2) second for the topping like:

```
id       1
topping  tomato
```

3) third for the relation beetween them - you can have one pizza with 0 or 10 toppings, and one topping can be related to many pizza

```
id_pizza   1
id_topping 1
```

This relation should cover all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on database you use. You describe only relative one. Then basically you need 3 tables:

```
pizza (id, name, toppings_ids AS ingredients), 

toppings (id, name), 

orders (id, pizza_id, topping_ids AS additional_toppings)
```

Assume your framework knows how to store and search through multiple ids

PS of course you need more columns in each table, like date or price, this sql-like schema represents only required for pizza fields